# Toyota matrix heat/hvac heater blend door actuator

Tags: toyota, heater, matrix

I have a toyota matrix 2005 xrs its blows full heat on the drivers side but cold on 
the passengers side sometimes just alittle heat will come on the passenger 
side thats when i drive for a bit also when i switch the dial to floor/defrost 
excetra the right side is cold ive checked the fluids good rad reservoir coolant 
perfect both hoses going into heater core are hot/hot/warm ok yes videos on 
theheater blend door actuator on the Pontiac vibe behind the glove on the left 
side there is none on mine mines on the right side ive looked nothing the one on 
the right that opens the flap it works where the air filter is it works it opens and 
closes i checked when i pressed the rec button what do i do wtf should i check i 
bought a heater blend door there is nothing on the left theres 1 on the right and 
i see it working plzz help tell me if theres one im missing

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's hard to understand what you're talking about with no periods or paragraphs; if you spend a bit of time editing your question you're more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Does your Matrix have dual climate controls, where the passenger side is controlled separately from the driver?